# Convert InlineImage in Google Docs to an HTML image

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a Google Docs add-on and I need to take an InlineImage from a Google Docs document and convert it to an HTML image.

My initial strategy was to take the data from the InlineImage and convert it to a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), but I've learned that apps script does not support this. Anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Where you'll be displaying the image? Inside the add-on or somewhere else?

Comment: It will be displayed inside the add-on sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the [Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/) template system [doesn't support data URIs](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1558), but you can work around this by switching your sidebar to use the [`IFRAME` sandbox mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode) instead. Since `IFRAME` mode doesn't use Caja, isn't subject to the same limitations, but there is a caveat: it's not compatible with older browsers. If you need to use data URIs, though, you don't have much other choice.

Here's an example script that will take a selected image and display it in the add-on sidebar using a data URI.

Code.gs:

```js
function getImage() {
  var els = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection().getRangeElements();
  var el;

  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    el = els[i].getElement();

    if (el.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
      return el;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

function showSidebar() {
  var mimetype = 'image/png';
  var blob = getImage().getAs(mimetype);
  var uri = 'data:' + mimetype + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());

  var sidebar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar');
  sidebar.data = uri;

  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(
    sidebar
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  );
}
```

Sidebar.html:

```html
<img src="<?!= data ?>" />
```